# How should I decide between handlerAdded and channelActive when a web client reach my websocket server?

Tags: java, netty

My program has a websocket server. The server catch the client's connection in two ways: 'handlerAdded' and 'channelActive'. Which should I use when web client comes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ChannelActive` is recommended, while on a server context, `handlerAdded` and `channelActive` are called after each other, when you port your handler to the client side, `handlerAdded` will be called before `channelActive` is called, making your code bug, since writes wont work untill the channel is active.

**In `handlerAdded`:** `channel().isActive()` is either true or false

**In `channelActive`:** `channel().isActive()` is always true<sup>*</sup>

You can only send messages to the other side when the `channel().isActive()` is true.